# How can I visualise what happens when we revolve around the $x$ or $y$-axis?

Tags: calculus

I can solve for the volume of one graph and for volume between two graphs. Yet I don't have an intuitive understanding of what mathematically happens when we revolve around either axis. Could you explain what actually goes on when my calculator calculates the volume? And is the behaviour any different when revolving around the $y$-axis?

What I'm essentially asking is: 'Why do the following formulas express the volume?'

---

For volume of one graph.
$$\int_{a}^{b} \pi (f(x))^2 dx$$
For volume between two graphs:
$$\int_{a}^{b}\pi ((f(x))^2 - (g(x))^2) dx$$

---

I'm amazed we can do this within graphs..

[image: Revolving around the x-axis]

Highly appreciated,

-Bowser

Comment: Perhaps you could make your question more specific.  Are you asking how the calculator actually performs the computations on the integrals that you have written?  Are you asking how to determine what the limits of these integrals are?  Are you asking for why the formulas that you have written expresses the volume?

Comment: @michaelburr I've added some specificity.

Comment: The short answer to your question is that it's in the Riemann sums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation and derivation is likely in your textbook. Essentially (intuitively), you take "infinitely thin" cylinders of height $dx$, each at different distances, $x$, from the $y-$axis. The radius of the circular cross section of the cylinder at each value of $x$ is $f(x)$. The volume of a cylinder is $\pi r^2 h = \pi (f(x))^2 dx$. The volume is the "sum" of the infinitesimal cylinders. When you add infinitesimals over an interval $[a,b]$ you use an integral.

$$V = \int_a^b \pi (f(x))^2 \ dx$$

The second formula is easily understood as subtracting an inner volume from an outer volume.

$$V = \int_a^b \pi (f(x))^2 \ dx - \int_a^b \pi (g(x))^2 \ dx$$

Like I said, a formal derivation using a limit process is probably in your textbook.

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to know whether there was more going on behind the scenes. Apparently not!